# Double zeta polarised, triple zeta double polarized. What is the definition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, computational-physics, orbitals, density-functional-theory

I understand that a single zeta basis contains the hydrogen stationary states $\psi_{nlm_l}$ for a particular selection of quantum numbers $(n,l,m_l)$. You can decide the quantum numbers that will be required in the basis by looking at the valence electrons for the atom that should be represented. I will briefly use chemists orbitals notation ($1s^2 \ 2s^2 \ 2p^6$ etc...). To get single zeta: match the quantum numbers $(n,l)$ corresponding to the valence electrons of the element that should be represented for *all* values of $m_l$. For example: Suppose you were trying to make a basis for Carbon, which has the valence electrons $2s^2 \ 2p^2$. Then you would have the following basis
$\{ \psi_{200}, \psi_{21-1}, \psi_{210}, \psi_{211}  \}$, which contains all orbitals of the types $2s$ and $2p$.

But what happens if we require double or triple zeta and single and doubly polarized basis? According to something I am reading, we should add additional radial shaped orbitals, and add more angular momenta to the basis. However, the author does not describe how this should be done exactly. Can you explain  which functions should be added to get double zeta polarized and triple zeta doubly polarized?

Comment: 6 months is a long time without an answer, you might try https://materials.stackexchange.com and use the basis-set tag, where 100% of the questions are answered so far.